# php curl with soap error: unable to handle request without valid action parameter

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl, asmx

I am sending a soap request via curl in php, and I get this response:

> Client Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter.
>   Please supply a valid soap action.

SOAP XML:

```
$url="http://www.site.com/soap.asmx";
$user = "test";
$password = "test";

$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Routing xmlns="www.site.com">
      <Login>test</Login>
      <Password>testy</Password>
   </Routing>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

CURL:

```
 $soapme = curl_init(); 
           curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_string); 
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) )); 
            curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);
            curl_setopt($soapme, curlOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
            curl_exec($soapme);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with CURL - your curl code is "perfect". It's your soap request that's invalid.

Comment: Ok off to a good start. What is the problem with the soap request? I received the script from a company and I made it into a string.

Comment: No idea. I've never used SOAP, but the error message seems obvious enough - there's no "action parameter".

Comment: haha ok. SO where do you 'think' I put an action parameter? I thought it refers to the header being incorrect.

Comment: Naw. the headers are fine. soap's just XML after all. Your `<soap:Body>` is empty though, and from a quick googling, that's apparently where the action verbs should go. So basically you're sending a null request.

Comment: I left out the body tags because its confidential. Im still looking into the action issue. Maybe I need a WSDL????

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see the actual message and action types expected by the SOAP Web Service and defined by the WSDL, then I can wager a bet that your Headers line is missing the SOAP 1.1 SOAPAction header:

```
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction: "Routing"', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) ));
```

Please note, I called the SOAPAction *Routing* but it really could be anything, depending as mentioned, on what the Web Service expects and WSDL defines.

Comment: I had the same problem, your answer finally showed me where do I need to put the action parameter. Thanks a lot m8.

Comment: np, glad it helped someone... also please note that some SOAP Web Services don't support the ***SOAPACtion*** being inside quotations, even though the SOAP1.1 spec[1] specifies the method/action call should be, so 

   ***SOAPAction: "Routing"***

would become

   ***SOAPAction: Routing***

Luckily, in SOAP 1.2 you can skip that somewhat confusing HTTP Header altogether

[1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528

Comment: uggh, comments markdown problem there... note to self: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting